# how to get SignalR user connection id out side the hub class?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, signalr

I am using SignalR in my ASP.NET web application. Here I am calling client from outside to hub class using `IHubContext`. I need to get the current user's connection ID in order to send messages to the current user only. How can I get the connection ID on the client side?

Comment: oh ok. Is there a way to get connection id of current user in the client side?

Comment: It's documented in the [SignalR wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client#connectionid)

Comment: Some dudes are just too mean on STACK OVERFLOW. Just give the dude a straight answer and stop redirecting the guy to a documentation. If you dont know the answer, stop responding. The guy is new to STACK. @Ruchira, thanks for ur straight forward answer. var c_id = $.connection.hub.id;

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yep. You can use `$.connection.hub.id`.

Comment: Notice that you have to wait for the callback: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41739017/564623

Answer (score 3):

For a .NET Client it is on the `Connection` object, inherited by `HubConnection`.

```
Connection.ConnectionId
```

So typically can be found on

```
hubConnection.ConnectionId
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another way also, you can get connection id into your controller from hub by invoking a method of `hub` and you can return the required `ID` from there.

**Controller Code**

```
var HubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<"ChatHub">(); //`ChatHub` can be your Hub Name
ChatHub HubObj= new ChatHub();
var RequiredId= HubObj.InvokeHubMethod();
```

**Code inside Hub**

```
public string InvokeHubMethod()
{
     return "ConnectionID"  //ConnectionID will the Id as string that you want outside the hub
}
```

Comment: this will return norhing but a string with "ConnectionID",

Comment: it is better to give rod than a fish :) @BaoucheIqbal, that gave me an idea how to invoke client method and get id.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var hub = $.connection.someHub;
// After connection is started
console.log(hub.connection.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Server : 
Context.ConnectionId 
=> "dJSbEc73n6YjGIhj-SZz1Q"

Client :

```
   this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {     
         var hub = this._hubConnection ;
         var connectionUrl = hub["connection"].transport.webSocket.url ;
         console.log(connectionUrl);
```

=>  wss://localhost:5001/notify?id=dJSbEc73n6YjGIhj-SZz1Q

you can extract the id.
(far to be a perfect solution)

Comment: what if the transport is not websocket ? eg: websocket is not supported in the browser, so the transport falls back to long polling ?

Answer (score 0):

use the following code it works for me.

in the hub class.

```
 public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType> MyUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyUserType>();



    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        MyUsers.TryAdd(Context.User.Identity.Name, new MyUserType() { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,UserName=Context.User.Identity.Name });
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

       Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

in the hub class file create the following class

```
public class MyUserType
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

and outside the hub class.

```
  var con = MyHub1.MyUsers;
       var conId =con.Select(s => s.Value).Where(s => s.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the full hub url, you can say: `hubConnection.connection.transport.webSocket.url`

this is something like: `"wss://localhost:1234/myHub?id=abcdefg"`

Regex to get the ID:

`var r = /.*\=(.*)/
var id = r.exec(url)[1]`

Comment: what if the transport is not websocket ? eg: websocket is not supported in the browser, so the transport falls back to long polling ?