# I am getting an undefined connection id in signalr javascript client

Tags: javascript, signalr

According to all documentation that i have come across i should be able to call $.connection.hub.id AFTER my connection has been started.  this is my code:

```
    var handshake = $.connection.handshakeHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.dir($.connection.hub);
        console.log('connection started with id: ' + $.connection.hub.id);
        self.parentConnectionId = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)connection\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
        handshake.server.connect(self.parentConnectionId, $.connection.hub.id);
    });
```

I am successfully connecting and the handshake proxy connect call hits the server so it is not like the connection is bombing.  I have also inspected the property in the dev tools after the connection and the ID is still undefined.

I have tried this with version 2.1 and 2.2 of Signalr and no luck.  Anyone have any experience with this? This is killin me.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else that may have been googling/searching this (like me), ensure you've started your hub and it's connected.

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("id : %o", $.connection.hub.id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I am an idiot.   I had the proxy script tag included in two different spots in my solution.  Removing one fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried handshake.connection.id and this worked for me