# Signal R for notifying the single authenticated user

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Following is the scenario I want to achieve using signal R.

If sending of email is going on then message will get display
Example: "Sending Email.."

Once email sending is done will show the another message to the same user stating
Example: "Email Sent successfully."

How I will achieve this with Signal R and sending the notification to the one user only.

Read the post which are saying use Connection Id but that will be changing not a fix 
I want to do this for the Authorized user only or we can say with static userid.

Answer (score 1):

I see two different approaches to the problem, with two different solutions. Either the server keeps track on which connectionId(s) that belong to a particular user. Or the client lets the server know which connectionId to use.

#### Option 1: Server knows how to map user to connectionId(s)

Firstly you need to map each user to the connectionId(s) they have. Bear in mind that the user could have several connectionIds as he/she could be logged on in multiple tabs or browsers. On the server it is difficult to distinguish between connections so when the user sends an email, it is easiest to notify on all connections that belong to that user.

There are several ways to keep track of users connectionIds. Here is a good [walk through](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections). In your case I think the UserID provider option would be a good fit, as it's easy to implement and sufficient if you only want to send updates to the current user.

#### Option 2: Client notifies server on connectionId to use

Another approach could be to include the connectionId in the call to the server. That way the server knows which connection to report back to. You can get the connectionId in Javascript (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19485136) answer) using:

```
var c_id = $.connection.hub.id
```

Hope this helps!